# Factory for client requests based on request identifier

Tags: java, design-patterns, dependency-injection, refactoring

In my program, I'm getting requests from the client via Java socket. Each request has a unique command identifier which corresponds to specified command on the application side.

Now I have a class with very large switch in it, which creates instances of command classes depending on received command ID. This class receives `ByteBuffer` with request data from client, and `ClientConnection` object (a class which represents connection between client and server). It reads the first two bytes from the `ByteBuffer` and gets corresponding command (instance of class that extends `ClientRequest` class).

For example:

```
public static ClientRequest handle(ByteBuffer data, ClientConnection client) {
    int id = data.getShort();  //here we getting command id
    switch (id) {
        case 1:
            return new CM_ACCOUNT_LOGIN(data, client, id);
        case 2:
            return new CM_ENTER_GAME(data, client, id);
        //...... a lot of other commands here
        case 1000:
            return new CM_EXIT_GAME(data, client, id);

    }
    //if command unknown - logging it
    logUnknownRequest(client, id);
    return null;
}
```

I don't like the large switch construction. My question is: Is there some ways to refactor this code to make it more elegant? Maybe use some pattern?

Also, in future I want to try to use dependency injection (Guice) in my program, could it be used for instantiating `ClientRequest` instances depending on received ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mapping an ID to a response object is a common task, but it is difficult to move away from somehow enumerating which ID maps to a specific response object. The `switch` block you have provided works, but it is not the most extensible. For example, if a new response object or ID is added, you would have to add a `case` statement to the `switch`.

One alternative is to create a map of IDs to a factory object that can create new response objects. For example:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ClientRequestFactory {
    public ClientRequest createClientRequest(ByteBuffer data, ClientConnection client, int id);
}

public class ClientRequestSwitchboard {

    private final Map<Integer, ClientRequestFactory> mappings = new HashMap<>();

    public ClientRequestSwitchboard() {
        mappings.put(1, (data, client, id) -> new CM_ACCOUNT_LOGIN(data, client, id));
        mappings.put(2, (data, client, id) -> new CM_ENTER_GAME(data, client, id));
        // ... Add each of the remaining request types ...
    }

    public ClientRequest createClientRequest(ByteBuffer data, ClientConnection client, int id) {
        ClientRequestFactory factory = mappings.get(id);

        if (factory == null) {
            return createDefault(data, client, id);
        }
        else {
            return factory.createClientRequest(data, client, id);
        }
    }

    protected ClientRequest createDefault(ByteBuffer data, ClientConnection client, int id) {
        logUnknownRequest(client, id);
        return null;
    }
}
```

You can then use the `ClientRequestSwitchboard` as follows:

```
private static final ClientRequestSwitchboard switchboard = new ClientRequestSwitchboard();

public static ClientRequest handle(ByteBuffer data, ClientConnection client) {
    int id = data.getShort();
    return switchboard.createClientRequest(data, client, id);
}
```

The benefit of this approach over the `switch` technique is that you now store the mapping information as dynamic data rather than as static `case` statements. In the dynamic-approach, we can add or remove mappings at runtime, rather than only at compile-time (by adding a new `case` statement). Although this may appear to be a slight difference, the dynamic-approach allows us to improve the solution much further.

If we employ a Dependency Injection (DI) framework, such as Spring, we can utilize some creative features in Java. For example, we can add new `ClientRequestFactory` instances (new entries in the map) by creating a new `ClientRequestFactory` classes. For example:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface ClientRequestFactoryForId {
    public int value();
}

@Service
@ClientRequestFactoryForId(1)
public class AccountLoginClientRequestFactory implements ClientRequestFactory {

    @Override
    public ClientRequest createClientRequest(ByteBuffer data, ClientConnection client, int id) {
        new CM_ACCOUNT_LOGIN(data, client, id);
    }
}

@Service
public class ClientRequestSwitchboard {

    private final Map<Integer, ClientRequestFactory> mappings = new HashMap<>();
    private final ListableBeanFactory beanFactory;

    @Autowired
    public ClientRequestSwitchboard(ListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
        this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void findAllClientRequestFactories() {
        Map<String, Object> factories = beanFactory.getBeansWithAnnotation(ClientRequestFactoryForId.class);

        for (Object factory: factories.values()) {
            int id = dataStore.getClass().getAnnotation(ClientRequestFactoryForId.class).value();

            if (factory instanceof ClientRequestFactory) {
                mappings.put(id, (ClientRequestFactory) factory);
            }
            else {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Found object annotated as @ClientRequestFactoryForId but was not a ClientRequestFactory instance: " + factory.getClass().getName());
            }
        }
    }

    public ClientRequest createClientRequest(ByteBuffer data, ClientConnection client, int id) {
        ClientRequestFactory factory = mappings.get(id);

        if (factory == null) {
            return createDefault(data, client, id);
        }
        else {
            return request.createClientRequest(data, client, id);
        }
    }

    protected ClientRequest createDefault(ByteBuffer data, ClientConnection client, int id) {
        logUnknownRequest(client, id);
        return null;
    }
}
```

This technique uses Spring to find all classes with a specific annotation (in this case, `ClientRequestFactoryForId`) and register each as a factory that can create `ClientRequest` objects. A type-safety check is performed, since we do not know if an object annotated with `ClientRequestFactoryForId` actually implements `ClientRequestFactory`, even though we expect it to. To add a new factory, we simply create a new bean with the `ClientRequestFactoryForId` annotation:

```
@Service
@ClientRequestFactoryForId(2)
public class AccountLoginClientRequestFactory implements ClientRequestFactory {

    @Override
    public ClientRequest createClientRequest(ByteBuffer data, ClientConnection client, int id) {
        new CM_ENTER_GAME(data, client, id);
    }
}
```

This solution assumes that the `ClientRequestSwitchboard` and each of the classes annotated with `ClientRequestFactoryForId` are beans that are known to the Spring application context (are annotated with `Component` or some other derivative of `Component`, such as `Service`, and the directory in which these beans exist are picked up by a component scan or are explicitly created in a `@Configuration` class). For more information, see [the Spring Framework Guru's article on Component Scanning](https://springframework.guru/spring-component-scan/).

---

**Summary**

- At some level, the ID to `ClientRequest` mapping must be established
- Establishing the mapping at runtime opens up many more options
- Spring can be used to decouple the dependency between factory beans that create `ClientRequest` objects and the `ClientRequestSwitchboard`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer Justin! I'd like approach with Map<Integer, ClientRequestFactory>, it seems more elegant than large switch, and has the advantages you mentioned. I just notified that here:         ClientRequest request = mappings.get(id);
not ClientRequest will be returned, but ClientRequestFactory. So, it should look like        ClientRequestFactory factory = mappings.get(id); ... return factory.createClientRequest(data, client, id); If i understand code correct

Comment: @NewJ You are correct: That was a typo. `ClientRequset request` should be `ClientRequesetFactory factory` and the `ClientRequest` is returned by calling `createClientRequest` on the `ClientRequestFactory` object. Thanks for catching that. I've updated the answer to correct those mistakes.